# How to create Menu in linux mint

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-mint

I am using linux mint OS. I want to create my own menu (eg like Internet).

How to create menu?

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, which uses the freedesktop.org standard for it's Menus.

You can find the latest spec for the free desktop menu standard [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/)